# Disable remote connection to mysql (Debian,Firewall)

Tags: mysql, debian, firewall

I want to disable outside connections to my mysql in debian, with firewall.
i only know that it has to be inside the iptables.test.rules file

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [so] is about programming questions; for questions about server administration, please use [sf].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to disable external connections to your MySQL is setting `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in `my.cnf` configuration file. If you still need to block MySQL external access using firewall, you drop or reject all packets sending to 3306 port.

Comment: When I do this I get the error: `mysql: unknown variable 'bind-address=127.0.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

To drop all packets sending to 3306 port use iptables:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```